# Copy Only Some Characters From TextView

Tags: android, string, copy, character

Is there any function in Android that allows me to copy only some characters from a TextView?

For example, if the TextView = "This is Good", how can I get only the string "Good"?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't retrieve all the text from the view and then process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is not "the one function" you are looking for. Instead the following will do what you want.

Get the text:

```
 String text = textview.getText().toString();
```

Then, with regard to getting "Good" in your sentence example, use the String.substring() function it:

```
String innerString = text.substring(8);
```

The substring above is for all characters from the 8th index onwards. A range can be specified instead if needed such as:

```
String innerString = text.substring(8, 10);
```

That will start from the 8th character and go up to (but not including) the 10th character.

Answer (score 1):

try StringBuilder class.
firt create StringBuilder object.

```
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(textview.gettext());
```

check methods available in this class [link for the class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)